# Send mail in php by using href

Tags: php, email, href

This is the message content

```
    <?php

    $message = "
    <html><body>
    <table border='1' width='100%' >
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope='col'>Product Name</th>
        <th scope='col'>Quantity</th>
        <th scope='col'>Total Price (RM)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    ";

     ?>
```

The Message as the Table

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $Display["SupplierEmail"]; ?>?subject=Buy a Product&cc=<?php echo $AdminEmail; ?>&body=<?php echo $message; ?>">Send me an email</a>
```

The Output become
[Opening Email Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN33M.png)

The Problem in the Image
[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrhVX.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN33M.png)

How to solve it?

Comment: This behavior is going to ride entirely on the client's designated mail program. And MOST (any worth their salt for security reasons) will refuse to render html as default email body from some random website link click. Sorry. You need to stick to Plain Text default message bodies for the `mailto:` hyperlinks for widespread compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Most email programs will not let you embed html, but I know it is not formatted all nice, but how about creating a from, fill it with default data?

```
<form action="mailto:postmaster@mydomain.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
   <input type="text" name="productname" id="productname" value="answer" />
   <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="42" />
   <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="everything" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

You could hide the form fields if you like and you can format is a bit with tabs and spaces

Comment: This is straight send right but no going to open the application?